# Reproduce ARIMA Forecast (Coefficients from R Arima())

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I am quite new to the R and the ARIMA model, and I have a question on the ARIMA model that I obtained in R.

I will use the US unemployment rate as an example, the data range is from Jan, 1948 to Feb, 2015, total of 806 observations. After looking at the AICc, I decided to use ARIMA(2,1,2) model. (BTW I am using Arima() function from "forecast" package in R)

The output is the following:

```
Series: log.unemp
ARIMA(2,1,2)

ar1 1.6406
ar2 -0.7499
ma1 -1.5943
ma2 0.7893

sigma^2 estimated as 0.001307: log likelihood=1530.14
AIC=‐3050.27 AICc=‐3050.2 BIC=‐3026.82
```

The code is

```
fit.best <- Arima(log.unemp, c(2, 1, 2), include.constant=FALSE)
print(fit.best)
```

Then I want to measure the forecast performance of this model. That is, to calculate things like RMSE, Theil's U, etc. But I do not know how to do that. The reason is that it seems that I do not know how to derive the forecast equation from this output to calculate the fitted values.

So could anyone help me on this? How should I derive the forecast equation from this output? Also, after obtaining the equation, how can I do the forecast in Excel to calculate the fitted values from the first data point (there are some numbers that are not available when you are calculating the fitted value for `t=1`)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

you can use `summmary(fit.best)` to view RMSE.
Or if you want to caluate by yourself you can derive residuals and fitted values like this:

```
fitted=log.unemp-fit.best$residuals
```

about the equation see [this](http://www.stat.pitt.edu/stoffer/tsa3/Rissues.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `forecast` package

```
fit.best <- Arima(log.unemp, c(2, 1, 2), include.constant=FALSE)
my_forecast <- forecast(fit.best, h=10) 

my_forecast  #will show the next 10 periods
# or use some detailed data like
plot(my_forecast$residuals)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Use arima model as below code:

   ```
   arimafit = arima(log.unemp, order=c(2,1,2))
   ```
2. Forecast using the below code:

   ```
   arima_future = forecast(arimafit, h=3)
   ```

   where `forecast` is the function to forecast for next whatever months you want.

   `h=3` means it will forecast for next 3 months.
3. If you want to check RMSE on the test data you can use `DMwr` package:

   ```
   metrics = as.data.frame(DMwR::regr.eval(<test_data_vector>, arima_future$point_forecast))
   ```

`test_data_vector` - is the test data vector which you can create while dividing your main dataset into train and test dataset.

`arima_future$point_forecast` - Is the vector point forecast vector you will get in step2.